# Prove that $N = \frac{(d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_n)}{\frac{1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{d_2} + ... + \frac{1}{d_n })}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that $$N = \frac{d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_n}{\frac{1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{d_2} + ... + \frac{1}{d_n }}$$  where $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $d_1, d_2, ..., d_n$ are divisors of $N$?

Comment: *all* divisors of $N$?

Comment: yeah, all divisors

Answer (score 9):

Let $V$ be the set of all divisors of $N$.

Then note that if $d\in V$ then $N/d\in V$. And there is a bijection $f:V\to V$ mapping $d\in V$ to $N/d\in V$.

So for each $d_i$ there is a unique $N/d_i$ and vice versa.

Thus, $\dfrac{\sum_id_i}{\sum_i\dfrac{1}{d_i}}=N.\dfrac{\sum_id_i}{\sum_i\dfrac{N}{d_i}}=N.\dfrac{\sum_id_i}{\sum_id_i}=N$

Comment: very nice, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: very nice!!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma(N)$ be the *sum of divisors* of $N$.

Then it is given that $$\sigma(N)=d_1 + d_2 + \ldots d_n,$$
where $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$ are *all of the divisors* of $N$.

Notice that
$$\sigma_{-1}(N)=\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{d_n}$$
and that
$$I(N)=\frac{\sigma(N)}{N}=\sigma_{-1}(N),$$
where $I(N)$ is the *abundancy index* of $N$.

This then finally gives
$$N = \frac{\sigma(N)}{\sigma_{-1}(N)} = \frac{d_1 + d_2 + \ldots d_n}{\frac{1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{d_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{d_n}}.$$